# add one Google font with a hook in Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, google-font-api

I try add one font with a variable:
When I try one word like: "Sofia" it works fine, but I tried with font with most two words string like "Sonsie One" or three, I can do that in pure javascript too and it the same error ?

I have "css?family=fonts.googleapis.com GET 400 Bad Request" in the console ?

```
global $fonts_l;
$fonts_l = esc_attr( get_option('fonts-l') );
echo $fonts_l;
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'add_google_fonts');
function add_google_fonts() {
  global $fonts_l;
  $fonts_l = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='.$fonts_l;
  wp_register_style('GoogleFonts', $fonts_l);
  wp_enqueue_style('GoogleFonts'); 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a + sign inbetween the words on two or more word fonts: http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sonsie+One

Comment: I found the solution, trim() then I add the space with a regex.